# Invert Avrdude signal for Reset pin

Tags: raspberry-pi, avrdude, icsp

Good day all,

I have a bit of a pickle on hand. I have a project where we would like to use ICSP to program an atmega328p. We can do this quite easily using Avrdude with a custom config file, however, on another design, we have an NPN used for Reset. This means that if the BJT receives a HIGH, the output will be low.

Is there any way to either modify Avrdude or a command, to invert the reset signal? Is there another way to add a layer of software in between Avrdude to invert that pins logic?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

[image]

For those that are wondering, we used a capacitor in series, to prevent any buggy code from locking the atmega in a reset state. Thus it can only pulse that pin, not keep it low indefintely. Any design tips on this would also be appreciated.

Best
Jonathan

Comment: So, you implemented hardware and then decided to see if you can invert something in software? Isn't development supposed to go the other way around (make sure that hardware can do something before getting to software)? I would still go with hardware modification. (I take it, you want to invert ResetAtmega_Pi, right? please confirm, it's unclear from the question)

Comment: Yes, I know. My normal design procedure would also be HW, then FW and SW. But long story short, that isn't an option for this case. Due to bad project management, and a pushed timeline with the global chip shortage, the PCBs have been made and soldered, and I dont have access to make a physical mod... Yep, we want to invert ResetAtmega_Pi

Comment: I take it ResetAtmega_Pi is just a GPIO on raspberry Pi?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the *Programmer Definitions* section in the avrdude manual:

"To invert a bit in the pin definitions, use = ~ <num>."

Where <num> is the pin number. So if the programmer definition in your avrdude.conf file has a line something like this:

`reset = 22;`

Change it to:

`reset = ~22;`

Answer (score 1):

Given that you have access to the source code there is *every* way to modify Avrdude;  but I'd start by reading the documentation, there is probably a simpler way to define a new type of programmer.

Also **avrp** might be worth a look, one of those two is more configurable than the other.